# No me funciona el logcat de android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Ayer me funcionaba perfectamente y leía los Log.d  y los errores y hoy me sale esto después de una actualización de Android Studio. No se como hacer que me vuelva a mostrar todo.

> 05-19 16:12:00.133 19011-19011/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to
>   resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
>
> 05-19 16:12:00.136 19011-19011/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while
>   delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
>
> 05-19 16:13:08.388 5448-5455/? W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A
>   SQLiteConnection object for database
>   '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db' was leaked!
>   Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly
>   and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
>
> 05-19 16:13:08.389 5448-5455/? W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A
>   SQLiteConnection object for database
>   '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/help_responses.db.18'
>   was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in
>   progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer
>   needed.
>
> 05-19 16:13:08.389 5448-5455/? W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A
>   SQLiteConnection object for database
>   '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/auto_complete_suggestions.db'
>   was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in
>   progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer
>   needed.
>
> 05-19 16:13:15.934 24397-24397/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up,
>   version: 10298
>
> 05-19 16:13:15.934 24397-24397/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run:
>   adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
>
> 05-19 16:13:15.961 24397-24397/? I/FA: To enable faster debug mode
>   event logging run:
>                                            adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app de.mdiener.rain.usa

Comment: Te sugiero agregues una imagen de como tienes tu configuración.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La actualización no creo que puede provocar no funcione el LogCat, te sugiero revises esto:

> - El dispositivo seleccionado este "online" y sea el que tenga la aplicación de la cual deseas obtener la información en el LogCat.
> - Revisar el paquete de la aplicación correcto, en ocasiones puedes no tener definido alguno o tener definido el de otra aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa el nivel del Log, selecciona uno de los siguientes valores:

> - **Verbose**: se muestran todos los mensajes de registro (configuración  predeterminada).
> - **Debug**: se muestran los mensajes de registro de  depuración que son útiles durante el desarrollo únicamente, como  también los niveles de
>     mensaje más abajo en esta lista.
> - **Info**: se  muestran los mensajes de registro esperados para uso regular, como  también los niveles de mensaje más abajo en esta lista.
> - **Warning**: se  muestran posibles problemas que todavía no se consideran como errores,  y los niveles de mensaje, más abajo en esta
>     lista. Error: se muestran  los problemas que generaron errores, y
>     también el nivel de mensaje,  más abajo en esta lista.
> - **Assert**: se muestran problemas que el  desarrollador espera que nunca sucedan.

Si lo tienes definido como **Verbose**, se mostrarán todos.

Recuerda también revisar los filtros, recuerda que puedes buscar por palabra o tener un filtro definido, si tienes una palabra definida solo los textos con esa palabra serán mostrados en el `LogCat`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mas información en la documentación oficial:

[**Escribir y ver registros en el LogCat.**](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html?hl=es-419)