# ¿Cómo compilar un apk que al parecer detecta cambios?

Tags: android, apk, ingeniería-inversa

He intentado hacer Ingeniería inversa al descompilar un apk con Apktool y volver a compilar, todo el proceso se realiza correctamente, pero al ejecutar la app se cierra inmediatamente. Al archivo apk no le modifico nada, eso me hace creer que tiene algún proceso que detecta el descompilado y evita su ejecución.. Añado los detalles.

- Uso ApkTool version 2.3.4
- La app se compila correctamente pero al ejecutar se cierra(No modifico absolutamente nada solo descompilo y vuelvo a compilar)
- Registro LogCat en Android Studio Packpage com.dts.freefire.FFMainActivity(Actividad Principal del Apk)

```js
2020-04-11 16:18:18.018 809-2211/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN typ=null flg=0x10200000 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.dts.freefireth/com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity}} from uid 10051 on display 0
2020-04-11 16:18:18.374 809-2057/? D/GameManagerService: handleForegroundChange(). pkgName: com.dts.freefireth, clsName: com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity,FgActivityName:com.dts.freefireth/.FFMainActivity
2020-04-11 16:18:18.523 809-2051/? D/MdnieScenarioControlService:  packageName : com.dts.freefireth    className : com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity
2020-04-11 16:18:20.295 809-3689/? D/WindowManager: openInputChannel mInputChannel: 4fc718e com.dts.freefireth/com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity (server)
2020-04-11 16:18:20.328 809-18760/? V/WindowManager: Relayout Window{4fc718ed0 u0 com.dts.freefireth/com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity}: viewVisibility=0 req=1280x672 WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#20 ty=1 fl=#81810500 pfl=0x20000 fmt=-3 wanim=0x103046f vsysui=0x600 needsMenuKey=2 naviIconColor=0}
2020-04-11 16:18:20.338 393-393/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=1770 createSurf (1x1),1 flag=4, com.dts.freefireth/com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity
2020-04-11 16:18:20.380 809-7422/? V/WindowManager: Relayout Window{648d1a8d0 u0 SurfaceView - com.dts.freefireth/com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity}: viewVisibility=0 req=1280x720 WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(1280x720) gr=#800033 ty=1001 fl=#4218 pfl=0x10040 fmt=2 naviIconColor=0}
2020-04-11 16:18:20.388 393-393/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=1771 createSurf (1280x720),2 flag=404, SurfaceView - com.dts.freefireth/com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity
2020-04-11 16:18:20.404 393-393/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=1772 createSurf (1280x720),-1 flag=20404, SurfaceView - com.dts.freefireth/com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity
2020-04-11 16:18:20.478 809-18771/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{4fc718ed0 u0 com.dts.freefireth/com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity}
2020-04-11 16:18:20.478 809-18771/? D/WindowManager: disposeInputChannel mInputChannel: 4fc718e com.dts.freefireth/com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity (server)
2020-04-11 16:18:20.490 809-18771/? D/WindowManager: openInputChannel mInputChannel: 4fc718e com.dts.freefireth/com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity (server)
2020-04-11 16:18:20.491 809-18765/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{648d1a8d0 u0 SurfaceView - com.dts.freefireth/com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity}
2020-04-11 16:18:20.492 393-1964/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=1771 Removed SurfaceView - com.dts.freefireth/com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity (2/11)
2020-04-11 16:18:20.492 393-5400/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=1771 Removed SurfaceView - com.dts.freefireth/com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity (-2/11)
2020-04-11 16:18:20.492 393-1965/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=1772 Removed SurfaceView - com.dts.freefireth/com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity (1/10)
2020-04-11 16:18:20.492 393-422/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=1772 Removed SurfaceView - com.dts.freefireth/com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity (-2/10)
2020-04-11 16:18:20.506 809-2222/? D/WindowManager: disposeInputChannel mInputChannel: 4fc718e com.dts.freefireth/com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity (server)
2020-04-11 16:18:20.506 393-1965/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=1770 Removed com.dts.freefireth/com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity (1/9)
2020-04-11 16:18:20.506 393-420/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=1770 Removed com.dts.freefireth/com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity (-2/9)
2020-04-11 16:18:20.510 393-422/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=1770 Removed com.dts.freefireth/com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity (-2/9)
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio  por favor revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, agrega más información ¿para que usas apktool , es una app que no es tuya? ¿Que se muestra en el LogCat? ¿Visualizas algún error? ¿En que consiste tu app, hace uso de APIs?, te comento que con los detalles que aportas los problemas pueden ser distintos., saludos.

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys he modificado la pregunta espero que ahora este mas claro amigo :-), saludos.

Comment: Gracias por modificar tu pregunta @HarlodFugi pero porque no leíste [ask] ? te sugiero lo realices. Si "la app se compila correctamente", entonces debes poder revisar el LogCat, si deseas desarrollar en Android el uso del LogCat es indispensable,   puede ser la diferencia entre buscar por días un error o encontrarlo en unos segundos.

Comment: No se exactamente como obtener el LogCat de un apk que no es mio, me puedes orientar @Jorgesys

Comment: revisa : https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/71388/95

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys ya tengo el registro del LogCat , ¿Me puedes ayudar a interpretarlo?

Comment: Esta parte del LogCat no indica el problema @HaroldFugi , busca donde mencione "Caused by".

Comment: @Jorgesys Desafortunadamente eso es todo el registro LogCat que se muestra, pero la app se cierra en el  móvil, que raro...Removed Surface View (Esa es la linea del LogCat que me hace sospechar aunque no se muestre como error)